# IPMI temperature sensor precision/type

Tags: ipmi

When I query the `T_AMB` sensor of a Sun Server X4-L using IPMI, using the `rmcp` interface in a simple [python-ipmi](https://github.com/kontron/python-ipmi/) based program (which uses the `GetSensorReading` IPMI command to get a sensor reading every second), the value of the sensor comes out as float without any fraction (say 28.0 C). When I display the value of the sensor using the `show /SYS/T_AMB` from the Service Processor console, it is displayed as float with non zero fraction (fluctuates between 27.750 and 28.000 C). Is this a limitation of the particular Service Process, the IPMI itself or possibly the way the program is coded ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`GetSensorReadingRsp`](https://github.com/kontron/python-ipmi/blob/master/pyipmi/msgs/sensor.py) message definition in the `python-ipmi` library, the actual reading value is defined as `UnsignedInt`. This corresponds with the [IPMIv 2.0 spec](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.pdf), notably section *35.14 Get Sensor Reading Command* which says the actual reading is stored in a single byte.